# directory not owned by the 'mysql' or '_mysql' user

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I recently installed MSQL for a Rails App. After some tinkering, I have an error starting `mysql` that reads as follows:

```
Warning:  The /usr/local/mysql/data directory is not owned by the 'mysql' or '_mysql' user.
```

Comment: "Not a programming question."

Answer (score 2):

in terminal as root (or do `sudo` + below command):

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```

Comment: Glad that worked for you, but on numerous OS's like 10.6 you actually want to make sure and use the _mysql user/group.